# AJAX, Subdomains and the 200 OK response

Tags: php, ajax, subdomain, cross-domain

A non-hypothetical but abstracted situation:

I have a domain www.foo.com, from which I'm making an AJAX POST to beta.foo.com.  Examining the XHR object, I see a response header of 200 OK, but no response text - I even get a response 12B long, which is the exact response (a 12-character string) that I'm expecting - but the response text is blank.

If this is a cross-domain issue, why am I getting 200 OK, and better yet - why am I seeing the PHP functions fire on the beta.foo.com side - yet getting no response?

Comment: Its not a cross domain issue.  There is no security model of any kind for AJAX.

Comment: Are you using firebug to see the response text?

Comment: Post your javascript code. Without seeing the code there is not enough  information here to fully debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do cross subdomains ajax calls that easy. There is something called [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that prevents you from doing that. If you want sort this issue you need to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) or [Iframes](http://ajaxpatterns.org/IFrame_Call).

Install firebug and you will see an http 200 code and an error: that error is SOP acting.

Comment: JSONP is the ticket in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're checking the responseText property. Is it possible your response is in XML format?

If you send an XML request, or the response type is `'text/xml'`, you will get a value for `responseXML`. I *believe* that the `responseText` property can be blank if it's in XML format.

Random example from google:

http://javascript.about.com/library/blajax08.htm