# Ajax, subdomains, 200 response, and images -- ok?

Tags: ajax, image, firebug, same-origin-policy, jquery-load

This is a very similar question to [AJAX, Subdomains and the 200 OK response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838668/ajax-subdomains-and-the-200-ok-response) (and [JavaScript Same Origin Policy - How does it apply to different subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543784/javascript-same-origin-policy-how-does-it-apply-to-different-subdomains)), but with a twist.  I have a situation in which:

- A domain (www.example.com)
- Where the page at a subdomain (sd.example.com/cat/id)
- Needs to make ajax-style requests to another subdomain (cdn.example.com)

In contrast to the aforementioned question, what I am requesting is images.

- GET requests of images (using jQuery $.load())

**This seems to be working just fine**.  Because it was working just fine, when someone pointed out it was generating errors in Firebug the same-origin policy didn't immediately occur to me.

- Images **ARE** loading at localhost (apache VirtualHost url of test.sd.example.com/cat/id)

However, now that it has come to mind thanks to that question I linked, I am concerned that this will not work reliably in production.

- Will this *continue* to work in a production environment -- and will it work reliably cross-browser?

> Answer: No -- it only **looked** like it was working; it wasn't really

- If not, how do I fix it?  (I don't think I can JSONP images...can I?)

> Answer: Continue setting src of image & wait to show until load event triggered.

- If so, how do I stop the Firebug errors?  If I can.  (They're scaring fellow devs.)

> Answer: Same as above -- get rid of step where actually doing GET request for image file.

**Initial Code**

```
function(imageUrl, placeTarget){
 var i = new Image();
 var img = $(i);
 img.hide()
 .load(imageUrl, function(e){
  // console.log("loadImage: loaded");
  placeTarget.attr("src", imageUrl);
  return true;
 })
 .error(function(){
  // error handling - do this part
  // console.log("loadImage: error");
  return false;
 });
 return;
} // loadImage
```

Comment: whats the reason for wanting to get the image data rather than use <img>?

Comment: Because the page has a slideshow whose images have an average total size of 375kb (but up to 2mb).  It seems less than optimal to when what is needed is to load the images as their turn comes in the slideshow. And, no, there are no thumbnails. (So I could just use <img> normally for the thumbs and then load the fullsize images in an iframe on click). And, yes, I think that's dumb. And, no, there's nothing I can do about it.  I suppose I could wrap all the locations where I'm currently using <img> in <iframe>.  Kinda nasty, but it would probably work & get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not insert the images into the page by creating image elements and setting the src. what could be simpler?

edit: ... via javascript

I'm not sure this is exactly right, but in jquery:

```
img = $('<img>');
img.attr('src', 'http://somewhere.com/some_image.jpg');
$('#place_to_add').append(img);
img.ready(fade_into_next);
```

Comment: Because the page has a slideshow with up to 100 images (avg 15) with sizes ranging from 12kb to 50kb (avg 25kb).  It seems most inefficient to add an average of 375kb (or up to 2mb) to initial page load when what is needed is to load the images as their turn comes in the slideshow.  Or asynchronously.  And, no, there are no thumbnails.  (So I could load the thumbs and then load the fullsize images in an iframe on click).  And, yes, I think that's dumb.  And, no, there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: I wasn't saying do this in html. I meant manipulate the DOM in javascript.

Comment: Um. I am.  Heck, maybe that's why it's working when it "shouldn't" be.  I am doing the $.load() request so that the image will be fully loaded before it's inserted (no fading in a half-loaded or unloaded image).

Comment: you can load elements like this without have problems with the same-origin policy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying (1) I can do exactly what I'm doing without having any problem?  Or are you saying (2) I should dispense with the "load" step and simply continue using the step where I set the src?

Comment: My understanding is that you can set the src of an image without causing cross-domain problems.

Comment: Well, yes, of course.  But what about waiting until the image is *actually loaded* to display it?  That's what $.load() was accomplishing.  In part.  Preloading & detection.  Should I dispense with that step and simply use $.load() as an event or Paul Irish's $.imagesLoaded() to detect when it's done and omit the step where I'm actually attempting a GET request?  Sounds alright...

Answer (score 0):

Checkt this post: [JavaScript Same Origin Policy - How does it apply to different subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543784/javascript-same-origin-policy-how-does-it-apply-to-different-subdomains)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't provide any more information than the question I linked did.  My question involves all of that information, but it also involves images.  Also distinct in my situation is that it's working right now: the images ARE loading.  Which, from what I have been reading, they should not be.  Are images or binary somehow treated differently?  Or is it just because it's localhost -- though I am still loading the images from the same production server.

Comment: Hah, actually looks like it's probably (though I'd like more detail still) because of the step where I'm rather straightforwardly setting the src to the url of the image.  I know the $.load() was working when I was using images on my localhost, but it's probably not now that I'm loading real ones...but I never noticed because it looks like it's working as the images end up loading anyways.